# Type 'org.primefaces.model.TreeNode' does not have type parameters

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I'm trying the example of the Primefaces [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/treetable/basic.xhtml?jfwid=74d9a), I faces this error:

```
Type 'org.primefaces.model.TreeNode' does not have type parameters
```

when trying to declare the treenode: `private TreeNode<Document> root;`

I know I can remove `<Document>` as error suggests, but how it worked in the showcase?

Comment: Your PrimeFaces version is probably older than the one used in the showcase. Please upgrade to 11 and try again.

Comment: yes, it's 6.2, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type parameter for `TreeNode` was introduced in PrimeFaces 11. If you are getting that error, your PrimeFaces version is older than 11.

Always check what version the PrimeFaces showcase is using compared to your version and consult the [migration guide](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/../migrationguide/migrationguide) to see what has changed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to that if you want to use the older version, check the older version of the showcase, https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-v8/ui/data/treetable/basic.xhtml.

In the older version, you don't need the type parameter `private TreeNode root;`.